# JAutodoc like plugin for C++

Tags: c++, javadoc

I am using Eclipse for C++ development and I am looking for a plugin like JAutodoc that will automatically provide Javadoc documentation for my C++ classes.

Anyone know how to get JAutodoc to do that for me or can recommend some other tool?

Answer (score 0):

[Doxygen](http://www.doxygen.nl/) might be what you are looking for. It is a javadoc-like system for C++. There is an eclipse plugin for it called [Eclox](http://home.gna.org/eclox/).

Comment: Thanks, its nice to know that there is a plug in to create the javadoc rom eclipse instead of running Docygon outside of Eclipse.  I was'nt clear in my message but I am lookign for an app that will aotumatically create the @param and @return tags.  thsi is what JAutoDoc says it can do:

Comment: JAutodoc is an Eclipse Plugin for automatically adding Javadoc and file headers to your source code.

Answer (score 0):

I am searching for the same, I haven't found a solution that I like yet, but take a look at this two project, I think with some tweaking can become an JAutodoc like for Objective-C

- https://github.com/brutella/comment-generator
- https://github.com/Bilalh/autoDoc